# How to make custom drawer with new react native expo-router drawer?

Tags: react-native, expo, drawer, expo-router

I am using Drawer from expo-router. I want the drawer contains user profile picture and name with navigation drawer items but it shows error: `couldn't find parent navigation with route 'screen1'`.

How should I code the CustomDrawerContent component?

Please check my code below:

```
function CustomDrawerContent({ drawerPosition, props, navigation }) {
  
  const insets = useSafeAreaInsets();
  const router = useRouter();

  return (
    <ScrollView style={{ flex: 1 }} >
      <View
        style={{
          height: 200,
          width: "100%",
          justifyContent: "center",
          alignItems: "center",
          borderBottomColor: "#f4f4f4",
          borderBottomWidth: 1,
        }}
      >
        <Image
          source={require("../../assets/icon.png")}
          style={{
            height: 90,
            width: 90,
            borderRadius: 65,
          }}
        />
        <Text>
          Jacob
        </Text>
        <Text>
          Product Manager
        </Text>
      </View>

      <Drawer.Screen name="screen1" />
      <Drawer.Screen name="screen2" />

      
    </ScrollView>

  );
}
```

```
export default function Layout() {
  return (
    <Drawer
      drawerContent={(props) => {
            
        return <CustomDrawerContent drawerPosition={undefined} {...props} />
      }}
      screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }}
      
    >
    </Drawer>
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

So it seems you want to use a custom drawer content, then:
you need to move the `<Drawer.Screen>` tags to Layout function's children.

```
export default function Layout() {
  return (
    <Drawer
      drawerContent={(props) => {
            
        return <CustomDrawerContent drawerPosition={undefined} {...props} />
      }}
      screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }}
      
    >
      <Drawer.Screen name="screen1" />
      <Drawer.Screen name="screen2" />
    </Drawer>
  );
```

And additionally to give styles to the drawer use the screenOptions.drawerStyle prop like:

```
<Drawer
     screenOptions={{
        drawerType: "front",
        drawerStyle: {
          backgroundColor: "pink",
          width: "100%",
        },
      }}
...
>
...
</Drawer>
```